# Class Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, class

I am trying to get completely to grips with class inheritence in Python. I have created program's with classes but they are all in one file. I have also created scripts with multiple files containing just functions. I have started using class inheritence in  scripts with multiple files and I am hitting problems. I have 2 basic scripts below and I am trying to get the second script to inherit values from the first script. The code is as follow's:

First Script:

```
class test():

    def q():

        a = 20
        return a

    def w():
        b = 30
        return b

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        a = q()
        b = w()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (a, b) = test()
```

Second Script:

```
from class1 import test

class test2(test):

    def e(a, b):
        print a
        print b


    e(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test2(test)
```

Can anyone explain to me how to get the second file to inherit the first files values? Thanks for any help.

Comment: which tutorial are you reading, again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say you messed up class definition with function stuff. It should look more like this:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 20
        self.b = 30

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_instance = Test()
```

and

```
from class1 import Test

class Test2(Test):

    def e(self):
        print self.a
        print self.b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_instance = Test2()
    test_instance.e() # prints 20 and 30
```

It looks like your problem is not (only) inheritance, but also **how to correctly [define classes in Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)**.

Some notes:

- Always use capitalized names for classes. That is more or less convention.
- As ruibm pointed out, every (non-static) method of a class has to have a first parameter that is named (by convention) `self`.
- You can create instance variables by setting them as `self.variable = value` in the `__init__` method.
- If you call `Test()` you get an object back. Unless you assign it to a variable, just calling `test2()` as you did in your second piece of code has no effect. Maybe it had in your case because defined your class in a weird way.

Comment: Much better than my answer. I shouldn't have been lazy to the point of not writing code! Well done. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, each member function (method) of a class should have a variable called `self` which is pretty much the `this` pointer/reference in C++, Java, C#.

Basically, to make your code work add `self` as the first argument to all methods. To assign/read member variables use `self.a` and `self.b` otherwise you're just creating temporary function variables the way you have it right now.